# Windows 2012 - Password change doesn't work

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, login

I logged into the Domain Controller. Using Active Directory, I changed the password for my user account. Then when I had to enter my password on a computer, it said that it was wrong. I entered the old password and it worked.

I tested this on other computers and some require the old password and some require the new password.

This must mean that the login credentials are not being updated within the network. How can I fix this?

---

**Update:** Our AD has about 15 users and roughly the same amount of computers. We have 1 DC and 1 domain.

Comment: This question can't be answered without more details. How big is your AD, how many DCs, are these on multiple sites, what about your network, did you run the Best Practice Analyzer, what else did you do to narrow down the problem?

Comment: Are you using AD credentials caching?

Comment: Our AD has about 15 users and roughly the same amount of computers. We have 1 DC and 1 domain. I did not run Best Practice Analyzer. I didn't know about that. I will do that soon.

Comment: I don't know if I am using AD credential caching. I will try to find out.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Are you sure that you **change** user password? Users password changed somewhere? Are you sure that the user changed **correct user** password (mey be you change another user)?

Comment: @Slipeer - I changed my password. I can sign into some computers with my old password. I can sign into some computers with my new password.

Comment: Does computers, that accept old password has access to domain controller?

Comment: @Slipeer - Thanks. The computers that accepted the old password were using the wrong DNS. I feel stupid, but that solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posibly computers, that accept old password has no access to domain controller (or can't found it) and auth user from [user credentials cache](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn751047%28v=ws.11%29.aspx#BKMK_CachedCredentialsAndValidation).